# Самое первое окно не поддаётся изменению

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer, qss

[image: Размер]

При запуске программы, начальное окно не сохраняет свой изначальный размер, а ломается...

Я указал `self.serfexedsize`, в методе `gotomane` (219) строка кода. Но эта фиксация работает, только тогда, когда я возвращаюсь в это окно из другого окна.

Как сделать так, чтобы самое первое окно запускалось с нужным размером.

Чтобы вы могли посмотреть, что ломается. Скачайте полный файл из гит хаба
https://github.com/Nanoxia123/wednesday18_00 файл apexx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте вызов метода `gotomain()` в конце конструктора класса `MainWindow`:

```
...
# Начало основного класса 
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
...

        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())  
# +++           
        self.gotomain()                                # <----  

        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        hbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0) #вроде можно без этого ????????????????????????????????????
        hbox.addWidget(self.stack)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]